# Python3: 00 + 00 == 00 works, but 01 + 01 == 02 Fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, leading-zero

I found, this in Python3:

```
>>> 00 + 00 == 00
True
```

While:

```
>>> 01 + 01 == 02
    File "<input>", line 1
01 + 01 == 02
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Why does the first example works while the second one fails? Should't it be better if both failed or both worked?

Comment: because you can input integers in `oct` or `hex` using leading zero, for example `0o71` == `0x39`, so `01` - its in octal/decimal/hex form? I don't know, `explicit is better than implicit`.

Answer (score 4):

From [Integer literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals):

> Note that leading zeros in a non-zero decimal number are not allowed.
>   This is for disambiguation with C-style octal literals, which Python
>   used before version 3.0.

You can read the lexical definitions to understand the rule to parse integer literals.